# Spotfire, exclude certain subsets of a column in a pie chart

Tags: pie-chart, spotfire, tibco

I want my pie chart to exclude some subsets within a column "Fuels."

This is my initial screenshot,

[image]

And this is the screenshot where I edited the link excel sheet, and deleted some rows that I don't want.

[image]

I want to know if there is any way that I can display the bottom pie graph within a pie chart property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Kim - You can exclude unwanted rows from the visualization using 'limit data using expression' option.

`Properties -> Data -> Limit data using expression`

**Example:**

In the example below, I have excluded 'App3' in the pie chart though it shows in the table.

[image]

**Limit data expression:**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer ksp. I edited your answer just for a small format

Comment: Thank you scsimon!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `Limit Data Using Expressions` you can code this logic into your custom expression directly. This is really beneficial when, for example, you may want to have multiple stats showing in a Bar Chart or Line Chart. If for one aggregate you wanted subset A,B and C and for the second aggregate you wanted B,C, and D, you couldn't limit the data on the entire chart or else your metrics would be off. Instead, just limit the expression.

```
MAX(IF([Fuels] = 'coal',[kg of measurement]))
```

This would be the equivalent of removing the rows from your subset, except it just ignores it for the value. You can obviously use `<>` or link many values together with the boolean operator `and / or`

```
MAX(IF([Fuels] = 'coal' or [Fuels] = 'natural gas',[kg of measurement]))
```

Using the "not" operator... to return all rows where Fuels doesn't equal coal.

```
MAX(IF([Fuels] <>'coal',[kg of measurement]))
```